# CURL PHP send files file extension error

Tags: php, file, curl, file-transfer

im trying to send two file via cURL to an API. It seems to work except the API is coming back and saying that the file type is not allowed. The response is:

```
string(189) 
{
    "StatusId": -1,
    "Success": false,
    "ReturnObject": null,
    "Message": "Please check the file format of the uploaded files. We currently only support .pdf .jpg, .png, .bmp and .gif file extensions.
}
```

As you can see, the API JSON response means it can see there are files but just thinks they dont have an extension. I have looked at the absolute URL of the file and file extension and they are all JPG or PDF. Any ideas?

Here is my cURL code:

```
 // send a file
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
        'ClientID' => $client,
      'file' =>
          '@'.realpath(__DIR__ . '/..').'/webroot/img/uploads/documents/'.$_FILES['image']['name'],
       'file2' =>
          '@'.realpath(__DIR__ . '/..').'/webroot/img/uploads/documents/'.$_FILES['image1']['name']
    ));
curl_setopt(
    $request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "authentication: XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: multipart/form-data;"));
curl_setopt(
    $request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
var_dump(curl_exec($request));

// close the session
curl_close($request);
```

Comment: what do you get if you echo out the path to the image? Does the path seem correct and does the file actually exist in that location?

Comment: Yep checked and double checked. If the file was blank then the API would return an empty string error so there is a file there... but it thinks its the wrong type.

Comment: .pdf files not supported with api - and may be the cause of error, and which version of php is used?

Answer (score 0):

What API are you using?

Without any specific information I just have to take a wild guess: The response from the API says

> We currently only support .pdf .jpg, .png, .bmp and .gif file extensions.

However, in your question you mention that the file extensions

> are all JPG or PDF.

Maybe the problem here is that your files have upper case extensions, e.g. .JPG and .PDF, but the API only accepts lower case extensions, e.g. .jpg and .pdf. Some file systems (e.g. FAT or NTFS on Windows) do not care about upper or lower case in file names, but other file systems (e.g. ext4 on Linux) do care. So try to change all extensions to consist of lower case letters only before you send the files to the API.

Another guess would be the file format, that is the *actual content of the file*, is not one of the file formats supported by the API. For example, somebody could take a text file `foo.txt` and rename it to `foo.jpg`. That would take care of the extension, but the content of the file is still text and not a JPEG image. Maybe the API does check that, too.